# MYSQLI Prepared Statements for inserting image into DB

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to insert an image into a DB with MySQLi prepared statements. What would I use for `bind_param`; would it be `s`, or is there one for "file"?

```
$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$imgInsert =$db->prepare("INSERT INTO cars (image) VALUES (?) WHERE model = ? ") 
  or die($db->error);
$imgInsert->bind_param('ss', $image, $model); $imgInsert->execute();
```

What's in the MySQL table:

> image blob NOT NULL

Comment: What type does the image column have in your mysql table?

Comment: Sidenote: MySQL [`INSERT Syntax`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) does not support the `WHERE` clause. So your query as it stands, will fail. However, [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) does support it.

Comment: did u try the below answer ?